# sql server - summing totals within a month/year

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing a sql server report that shows running daily, monthly, and yearly totals at the bottom of the report.

I figured out how to do the daily report by taking the datediff of the "timestamp" field and a getdate() and returning rows that were = 0. That way I knew the difference in dates was 0 days and thus part of the daily total.

I am running into an issue as to a good way to do this with month and year. Here is the query I have for month calculation and it is giving me way more results than it should (I have another table which i'm using to double check my calculations. I should get about 300 as my total but the query below gives me about 7400 instead. Just a little off)

```
     SELECT     SUM(Rc0) AS Good, 
                      SUM(Rc0 + Rc1 + Rc2 + Rc3 + Rc4 + Rc5 + Rc6 + Rc7 + Rc8 + Rc9 + Rc10 + Rc11 + Rc12 + Rc13 + Rc14 + Rc15 + Rc16 + Rc17 + Rc18 + Rc19 + Rc20 + Rc21 + Rc22 + Rc23
                       + Rc24 + Rc25 + Rc26 + Rc27 + Rc28 + Rc29 + Rc30 + Rc31 + Rc32 + Rc33 + Rc34 + Rc35 + Rc36 + Rc37 + Rc38 + Rc39 + Rc40) AS Not_Good  
FROM         someTable WHERE     (MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(GETDATE())) and (YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

edit: alternate form of query that is giving me same result

```
SELECT     SUM(Rc0) AS Good, 
                      SUM(Rc0 + Rc1 + Rc2 + Rc3 + Rc4 + Rc5 + Rc6 + Rc7 + Rc8 + Rc9 + Rc10 + Rc11 + Rc12 + Rc13 + Rc14 + Rc15 + Rc16 + Rc17 + Rc18 + Rc19 + Rc20 + Rc21 + Rc22 + Rc23
                       + Rc24 + Rc25 + Rc26 + Rc27 + Rc28 + Rc29 + Rc30 + Rc31 + Rc32 + Rc33 + Rc34 + Rc35 + Rc36 + Rc37 + Rc38 + Rc39 + Rc40) AS Not_Good
FROM         someTable
WHERE     convert(varchar(7), timestamp, 126) = convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126)
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: timestamp is datetime, tray is int, RC0 - RC40 are int

Comment: I'm assuming you want a running total of the last 30 days as a monthly total, not a calendar month? And you want a sum of all 40 columns?

Comment: I want to return all data where the month of the datetime value in the timestamp field matches the current month. I show it as two fields (sum RC0) and (sum RC0-RC40), not 40 individual columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--As a generic sort of grouping including most spans.....

SELECT 
    'Year' = DATEPART(Yy, rowdate), 
    'Month' = DATEPART(Mm, rowdate), 
    'Week' = DATEPART(wk, rowdate), 
    'Total' = sum(yournumericfield)

FROM sometable

GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(Yy, rowdate), 
    DATEPART(Mm, rowdate), 
    DATEPART(wk, rowdate)

ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(Yy, rowdate), 
    DATEPART(Mm, rowdate), 
    DATEPART(wk, rowdate)